# Why BufferedWriter is writing the data into the file partially?

Tags: java, java-io, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I am trying to write a *json file* using this code:

```
        File f = new File("words_3.json");
        if (!f.exists()) {
            f.createNewFile();
        }
        if (fileWriter == null)
            fileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String text = scanner.nextLine(); 
                    fileWriter.append(text);
                    System.out.println("writing : "+text);
        }
```

Statement `System.out.println()` shows all text in the terminal.

When I'm checking the output file, I see that only `1300` lines has been written, while there are more than `2000` lines available.

Comment: To me that sounds as if you're not properly closing the `BufferedWriter`. Can you show how you open and close it?

Comment: I didn't closed the bufferedWritter as the writer writing value while the loop running.
let me check that

Comment: 2thanks, when I close `BufferedWriter` . it write all text in the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *data* that you're writing in to an output stream **isn't guaranteed** to reach its destination immediately.

The `BufferedWritter` is a so-called *high-level stream* which decorates the underlying stream that deals with a particular destination of data like `FileWriter` (*and there could be a few more streams in between them*) by buffering the text output and providing a convince-method `newLine()`.

`BufferedWritter` maintains a **buffer** (*an array of characters*) with a default size of `8192`. And when it ***gets full***, it hands it out to the underlying *low-level  stream*. In this case, to a `FileWriter`, which will take care of encoding the *characters* into *bytes*.

When it's done, the JVM will hand the data out to the ***operating system*** via `FileOutputStream` (*because under the hood character streams are build on top of bite streams*).

So, the data written to the *buffer* will appear in a *file* in *chunks*:

- when the *buffer* ***gets full***;
- and after the *stream was **closed***.

[**Javadoc**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#close()) for method `close()` says:

> Closes the stream, **flushing** it first.

I.e. before releasing the resource `close()` invokes method [`flush()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#flush()) which forces the cached data to be passed into its destination.

If no exception occur, everything that was written into the stream is guaranteed to reach the destination when the stream is being closed.

You can also use `flush()` in your code. But it has to applied with great caution. Probably when you deal with large amounts of critical data and which is useful, even when partially written (*so in case of **exceptions** you'll lose less information*). Misusing the `flush()` could significantly reduce the performance.

Comment: _"The JVM hands it out to the operating system, which will store this data in the cache."_ this is not correct, a buffered writer has a *buffer* inside Java.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I know that. So when `BufferedWriter` will pass its *8 KB* of data to the system, it'll be written as soon as possible? Or it depends on something?

Comment: The actual write to disk might be delayed by the OS, but in general, when another process tries to read the file, the OS cache will flush (or the read will be satisfied from the cache), so the problem here is wholly inside the JVM, and dragging the OS into it is an unnecessary complication.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for explanation. I've amended the answer.

Comment: Duplicates are only automatically removed if the question has no answers. Sometimes people will vote to delete a duplicate, but this is not what should normally done (duplicates serve as sign posts to the other question). However, if you want you can delete your answer here and post it on the duplicate.

Comment: When the `BufferedWriter`’s buffer is full, it just hands the data over to the underlying `Writer`, which is still a Java class. In case of `FileWriter`, it has to encode the characters to bytes, which requires a `ByteBuffer`. Only when this buffer is full (or flush/close happens), the actual bytes are handed over to the `FileOutputStream` which will call into the operating system). Since the encoded 8192 chars may need more than 8192 bytes, it’s possible that some of them are written and the remaining get buffered in `FileWriter`’s byte buffer when `BufferedWriter`’s buffer is full.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for point out on these details, I've updated the answer.